# How to save BigQuery query results to another table?

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I want save query results into new table.
With BigQuery online editor like [bigquery.cloud.google](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries) i easily do it with [micro-solution](https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/613313661776621568) from Felipe Hoffa.
Results with ~150.000.000 rows inserted with several seconds.

But how do i run query with "Destination Table" parameters **via BigQuery API**?

Comment: Set the configuration.query.destinationTable.* fields in the job configuration, then call jobs.insert?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert has more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [`Jobs.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) API call.

For example, in Java:

```
[...]
TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
tableRef.setProjectId("<project>");
tableRef.setDatasetId("<dataset>");
tableRef.setTableId("<name>");

JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery();
queryConfig.setDestinationTable(tableRef);
queryConfig.setAllowLargeResults(true);
queryConfig.setQuery("some sql");
queryConfig.setCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED);
queryConfig.setWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND);

JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration().setQuery(queryConfig);
Job job = new Job();
job.setConfiguration(config);

Bigquery.Jobs.Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert("<projectid>", job);
JobReference jobId = insert.execute().getJobReference();
[...]
```