# How to store federated table data in a historical table daily - Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

We are attempting to do something in BigQuery that we think should be fairly straightforward but are running into a brick wall. We essentially want to take data from a federated big query table and copy it, daily, into an "historical" table.

In SQL this could be easily achieved using INSERT INTO and a SELECT query but this doesn't seem possible in BigQuery.

Is there a simple way to insert the results of one query into a different table using the BigQuery API, ideally from a Google Script attached to a Google Sheet?

Comment: Have you read documentation for jobs.insert? Should be very simple. What you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Materializing BigQuery data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522145/materializing-bigquery-data)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to insert the results of one query into a
>   different table using the BigQuery API, ideally from a Google Script
>   attached to a Google Sheet?

You can check [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) API for details, but quick example below show how it can look for apps script

```
var myQuery = 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10'
var myProjectId = 'XXXXXXXX'
var myDatasetId = 'YYYYYYYY'
var myTableId = 'History'

var job = {
  configuration: {
    query: {
      query: myQuery,
      writeDisposition:'WRITE_APPEND',
      destinationTable: {
        projectId: myProjectId,
        datasetId: myDatasetId,
        tableId: myTableId
  }}}};

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, myProjectId);
```

You can see more about [BigQuery and Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery)